# pod lib lint error for objective C library

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, cocoapods

I am developing new version for Mapp Intelligence library (https://github.com/mapp-digital/MappIntelligence-iOS-v5) and I had to rename few classes at the latest version to avoid collision with some other library when they are added together.
After that when I run pod lib lint command if gives me errors for every renamed class that can not find the relative path for it.

`Encountered an unknown error (No such file or directory @ realpath_rec - /Users/***/Desktop/novagrana/MappIntelligence-iOS-v5/MappIntelligence/UserMatching/DeviceID/APXIdentifier.h) during validation.`

and **APXIdentifier.h** is an old name not renamed one.

I have tried to remove derived data few time and I also tried to remove completely cocoa pods and install them again, also **pod cache clean --all**  command does not help.

It must be some caching problem, but I do not know what I need to clean or remove.